# Glossary view: Show all results separated by letter

Tags: views

I have a glossary view set up.  When I go to example.com/glossary/all, all of my results are shown, but I'd like them to be separated by letter. The layout I'm looking for is exactly like this...

https://drupal.org/glossary

For example..

**A**

- Amy
- Angie
- Annie
- Amanda

**B**

- Billy
- Bob
- Ben

**C**

- Catwoman
- Cathy
- Crystal
- Caitlyn

Is there a way I accomplish that with Views?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354638/drupal-7-views-3-glossary-mode-where-is-it

Comment: Yeah I know how to make the glossary, its the grouping of the results on the View All page that I'm wanting to do. I think I may have figured out a way to do it. I pulled in the Title field a second time, rewrote it to only show the first letter, and set the grouping to that field. Seems to work good but I'm open to others suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Glossary](https://drupal.org/project/glossary) module.

> The glossary module scans posts for glossary terms (including
>   synonyms). The glossary indicator is inserted after every found term,
>   or the term itself is turned into an indicator depending on the site
>   settings. By hovering over the indicator, users may learn the
>   definition of that term. Clicking the indicator leads the user to that
>   term presented within the whole glossary or directly to the detailed
>   description of the term, if available.

or

[Lexicon](https://drupal.org/project/lexicon)

> A lexicon is a stock of terms used in a particular profession, subject
>   or style; a vocabulary. The Lexicon module generates one or more
>   Lexicon pages based on terms in taxonomies and optionally marks terms
>   in the content and links them to the appropriate Lexicon page.

or

take a look at [G2 Glossary](https://drupal.org/project/g2) module.